# Probability of getting an average of 3 or more by rolling 4 sided die twice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What I understood is the sample mean of two rolls of all sample space(16) as given below:

```
{(1, 1): 1.0,
 (1, 2): 1.5,
 (1, 3): 2.0,
 (1, 4): 2.5,
 (2, 1): 1.5,
 (2, 2): 2.0,
 (2, 3): 2.5,
 (2, 4): 3.0,
 (3, 1): 2.0,
 (3, 2): 2.5,
 (3, 3): 3.0,
 (3, 4): 3.5,
 (4, 1): 2.5,
 (4, 2): 3.0,
 (4, 3): 3.5,
 (4, 4): 4.0}
```

i.e. it forms a normal distribution and computing chances of getting >=3 is

```
(1+2+3)/16 = 37.5%
```

Here order mattered.

Without writing down all possibilities, is it possible to calculate the same?
If so, then how could we in both cases-where order matters and it doesnt.

Comment: It is not a normal distribution but, with two dice, a discrete triangular distribution.

Comment: In real life, order matters when counting equal-probability events unless you have Bose–Einstein dice.

Comment: Rolling the two dice and taking pairs of values as events, the events are equally likely only if order matters when the pairs are written. If we consider $(1,2)$ to mean either die shows a $1$ and the other shows $2$, then $(1,2)$ is twice as likely as $(1,1)$. The probability that the average is $3$ or greater is the same, however, so why make things so complicated? But if "the case where order doesn't matter" means to you that $(1,2)$ and $(1,1)$ are equally likely, do you have a physical model in mind that generates probabilities like that?

Comment: by order doesnt matter, I mean (2,1) and (1,2) are same.
by order matters means they are different events.

Comment: @Henry what I meant by normal was if the population was in millions, finding all those means would be cumbersome and denoting by a normal curve easier.

Comment: @Henry  i am confused if this problem can be restated as a binomial distribution.

Comment: It is a discrete uniform distribution for one die. It is a discrete triangular distribution for two i.i.d. dice.  With a large number of dice you can use the Central Limit Theorem to use a normal approximation (perhaps with a continuity correction) though it may be a poor approximation in the tails.

Comment: @Henry yes it tends towards a uniform distribution.
if i rephrase the question, "what is the probability of sum of 2 successive rolls to be 6 or more?", how would one approach it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a formula: if you roll two independent fair $n$-sided dice, then

- for $1 \le x \le n+2$ the probability the sum is $x$ or more is $1-\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)}{2n^2}$
- for $n+1 \le x \le 2n+2$ the probability the sum is $x$ or more is $\dfrac{(2n+1-x)(2n+2-x)}{2n^2}$

Comment: How did you come by that? Can you explain the logic in the answer, reference link where derivation to this is given.

Comment: $1+2+3+4+\cdots$ and some minor manipulation

Comment: 1+2+3+4+⋯?? how does that come along?

Comment: $1$ way of getting $2$ or $2n$, and $2$ ways of getting $3$ or $2n-1$, and $3$ ways of getting $4$ or $2n-2$, and . . .